# Javascript: check if an url is valid and starts with "http//" or "https://"

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test my urls validity , which should start with **http://** or **https://** ,

i ve used this **RegExp** :

```
private testIfValidURL(str) {
    const pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
      '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
      '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
      '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
      '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
      '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // fragment locator
    return !!pattern.test(str);
  }
```

This would work , execpt one case :

To consider it as valid , my urls should always start with `http://`
 or `https://`  , but with my function , urls like `www.abcd.com` would be treated as valid urls which is not enough for me.

**Sugesstions ?**

Comment: What is a "valid" url for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `^(https?:\\/\\/)?'` to `^(https?:\\/\\/)'`, the `?` means that you want to match zero or one occurnece of a pattern. You actually want exactly one occurence, so don't use `?` :)

From [regular-expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html):

> ? - Makes the preceding item optional. Greedy, so the optional item is included in the match if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `(...)?` chars, so it will be mandatory to have a http or https sequence first.

```js
function testIfValidURL(str) {
  const pattern = new RegExp('^https?:\\/\\/' + // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // fragment locator

  return !!pattern.test(str);
}

console.log(testIfValidURL('www.abcd.com'));
console.log(testIfValidURL('http://www.abcd.com'));
console.log(testIfValidURL('https://www.abcd.com'));
console.log(testIfValidURL('htt://www.abcd.com'));
```